# Are Comments and Posts the same

Tags: database, design-patterns, relational-database

I'm currently in the process of building another generic Blog style website, and I got to thinking. Where I usually use a separate table for `Posts` and another for `Comments` and then join them using FK's. I began to wonder, are they really worthy of separate tables?

For example properties they both share include:

- ID (int)
- Title (string)
- Body (text)
- Poster (FK)
- Created At (Datetime)
- Updated At (DateTime)
- Likes/Dislikes(ints)
- Etc..

One `Post` Has(optional) Many `Comments`,Many `Comments` have one `Post`, but also One `Comment`, may also have many `Comments`.

Now would it make more sense. For a table to contain both, Comments and Posts, and self reference them from within? Having a separate lookup table for containing what each type of entity is.

Then however, if a Post is a Comment, and a comment is no different to a post. Except for in a view context, should posted Images also be contained within the same table? As these to, can have likes/comments/name etc.

**Question in short:** Do blog Posts and Comments belong in the same table?

Comment: Mess yourself up some more. Ask if they can't be done in XML or JSON where your data is really just a document and the post and comments are just attributes. Then store them in some nosql database. There are too many ways to do things like this. You are asking for opinions here, as there is no real right or wrong answer depending on your circumstance. I can ease your pain a bit by saying that yes, you could generalize posts and comments as being the same thing but different. Or not. :)

Comment: Over thinking it, and I should stick with my usual Posts in one table and comments in the other. Do you mean :')

Comment: In some ways, and in some ways not, they are *the same type of thing*. Google 'site:stackoverflow.com philipxy database subtypes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to offer you a practical answer.

As a rule of thumb, when you have two apparent sub-types with only one or two different predicates then it isn't necessarily helpful to store them in separate physical tables.

Your logical model should make a distinction between posts and comments, because they have different relationships.

For your physical model, you really only have that one different predicate, according to your description.  The basic difference between a post and a comment seems to be the foreign key which references a parent post/comment.  I'm assuming you would say a post cannot have a child post, whereas you have said that a comment can have a child comment.

With this being the only difference, I would say that for practical purposes your physical tables should combine posts and comments.

**How can you decide in general?**

In general it's not cut and dry when to physically sub-type your tables.  All design is trade-offs.  What I look for are the number of different columns between two sub-types, but also I look at what those columns are and how much they might impact my application logic.

Having more than a few different predicates is usually a pretty good sign that you should be sub-typing physically.  However, if these columns are just coming along for the ride, as it were, and don't impact your application logic too much, then maybe they should just be nullable columns on a combined table.

On the other hand, maybe there is only one different column between two sub-types, but that column completely changes the way your application behaves.  In that case, maybe for the sake of keeping your code cleaner you should physically sub-type for that column alone.